# Error when using extern in c++

Tags: c++, c, mbed

I am working on a project where I have to receive a UDP packet through a WiFi module and process it. However, I am still a beginner in c/c++ (Student).
In my main file **main.cpp**, I used the UDPSocket class to initialise the communication between my module and the server.

```
UDPSocket server(&eth);
static void nsp_init()
{
  NSDL_DEBUG("name: %s", endpoint_name);
  server.open("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", xxxx);

  NSDL_DEBUG("name: %s", endpoint_name);


  NSDL_DEBUG("EP:%s\n", endpoint_name);
}
```

The problem  is in my **processing.cpp** file where I want to access the recv instance of the class I have declared in my main.cpp :

```
#include "ESP8266Interface.h"
#include "UDPSocket.h"

extern Serial pc;
extern ESP8266Interface eth;
extern UDPSocket server(&eth);   //Am getting an error for using this
extern char endpoint_name[16];
extern uint8_t ep_type[];
extern uint8_t lifetime_ptr[];
```

My question is how can I use the same **UDPSocket server(&eth)** I declared in my main class?

I do really appreciate your input...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `extern` declaration for an object should not have an initializer, unless you want the declaration to be a definition (in which case, `server` is multiply defined, causing a linker error). Normally, you would leave off the initializer in the declarations and have it only on the definition; the initialization is done by the translation unit in which the object is defined. So the declaration would simply be:

```
extern UDPSocket server;
```

An `extern` object declaration is a bit like a forward declaration of a function. Best practice is to put these in header files. So you should probably move the `extern` declarations of `server` and other variables into some `foo.h` file and the definitions into `foo.cpp`, and have `main.cpp` and `processing.cpp` both include `foo.h`.